# Plex used to work, but I can't find what I did before reinstalling my OS

Tags: permissions, symbolic-link, plex

I'm working on an old HP tower that seems to not like any of the updates being pushed by Ubuntu. So I am still running 16.04. A recent update broke my entire system and I had to reinstall my OS. Since doing that I have not been able to find how I set the permissions for plex to be able to see my media folders.

They are currently split between two drives at the following locations /SharedSpace/Videos & /MyBook/Videos. This all worked last week and now I can't seem to find instructions that allow plex to access those folders to populate the library.

I also can not find where how to move the plexMD folder from the home directory to a partition that has more space.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the output of my `df -h` command

```
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                    1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   388M  6.5M  381M   2% /run
/dev/sda9                20G  2.1G   17G  12% /
/dev/sda6                20G  3.6G   15G  20% /usr
tmpfs                   1.9G   51M  1.9G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                   1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0               89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/6964
/dev/loop1               90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6818
/dev/loop2               89M   89M     0 100% /snap/plexmediaserver/13
/dev/sda8                20G  106M   19G   1% /boot
/dev/sda5                20G   13G  5.8G  69% /home
/dev/sdb1               2.8T  2.5T  272G  91% /MyBook
/dev/sda4               1.8T  1.4T  391G  78% /SharedSpace
tmpfs                   388M   44K  388M   1% /run/user/1000
/home/erskine/.Private   20G   13G  5.8G  69% /home/erskine
/dev/sr1                7.7G  7.7G     0 100% /media/erskine/E2938
```

Comment: Are your files for Plex on external drives?

Comment: /MyBook is external and /SharedSpace is a partition on an internal drive.

Comment: These are their entries in /etc/fstab

# /SharedSpace was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=A545-4CD0  /SharedSpace    vfat    utf8,umask=007,gid=46 0       1

/dev/disk/by-id/usb-WD_My_Book_1140_574343315430313532313934-0:0-part1 /MyBook auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=MyBook 0 0

Comment: I edited the main post and I don't recall exactly how I installed plex. I know i used the Ubuntu Software app and then I did some work through the terminal. I can see the plex server running through my browser, but I can not navigate to the desired folders to add libraries.

Comment: I am fine if i need to purge and reinstall. Is there a preferred way to do that?

Comment: I went through that and now the localhost doesn't work  sudo apt install plexmediaserver
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
plexmediaserver is already the newest version (1.15.4.994-107756f7e).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 308 not upgraded.

Comment: yes, my steps were 1) sudo snap remove plexmediaserver, 2) enable repositories from the link you provided 3) sudo apt install plexmediaserver

Comment: Thank you so much, that seems to be working. Do you have any advice on how to move the metadata folder to a separate location? I think i remember it involved setting up a symbolic-link.

Comment: Thanks, that looks exactly like the instructions I followed last time.

Comment: Converted my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the snap version of Plex Media Server can have the problem of not being able to read into other folders on the drive due to containment of the application.  To solve this, first remove the snap version of Plex

```
sudo snap remove plexmediaserver
```

Following this [link here](https://support.plex.tv/articles/235974187-enable-repository-updating-for-supported-linux-server-distributions/) add the Plex repository to your system

```
echo deb https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list
```

Add the key

```
curl https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-keys/PlexSign.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Update the system and install Plex Media Server

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install plexmediaserver
```

If it complains that it is already installed, it would be best to reinstall it

```
sudo apt install --reinstall plexmediaserver
```

Run Plex normally.  The following link can help with moving the metadata to another location for safe keeping.

https://smyl.es/how-to-move-plex-metadata-and-index-data-to-new-driver-andor-directory-location/

Hope this helps!